what's the bests practices in date
What's the best practices with a date field when you want to fill in the fact that it's not filled in and not leave it NULL?
should you put 1999-01-01, 9999-09-09, 1890-12-31...?
Are there any rules for this?

It's very simple really! The general rule is to always use the correct type for your field - in the case of the DATE type (all of the following also applies to your DATETIME, TIMESTAMP and TIMESTAMPTZ types).
This (normally) means factors such as timezones and leap years (e.g. this year!) are taken care of for you when you add intervals (mins, hours, days, weeks, months, years) or combinations thereof.
If you have to use NULLs, then use them - I would avoid (but not totally eschew) if possible for two reasons:

less complex logic, and

the more you can tell the server, the better (again, normally) the choices the optimiser can make!


Using NULL is a much better solution for unknown (as opposed to empty) data than the use of "dummy" (aka "synthetic" or "sentinel") values, for three reasons:

if you have a dummy value, developers have to remember what that is and code around it - i.e. if your dummy value is, say, 1899-12-31.999999, then you might have queries of the form
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field < 2020-01-01 00:00:00 AND my_field >= 1900-01-01; -- note the extra AND clause!
which will involve performing this operation (or similar) for many queries in your system! Less cognitive load on your devs (poor darlings...).

3-value logic (at least as applied to databases) is relatively well known and understood - or at least should be(!) by devs. There are (unfortunately <sigh...>, there's always one!) some outliers - the most egregious offender in this case is Oracle which treats the empty sting ('') and NULL as the same, i.e. equal to NULL). If you know that Jim doesn't have a car, the empty string is an appropriate value for the car_brand field and not NULL(*)! Again, less cognitive load = fewer bugs.

Portability - the PostgreSQL DATE type range extends from 4713 BC 5874897 AD (guess who won't be debugging the Y5874.897K problem!), but MySQL's range is from  1000-01-01 to 9999-12-31 - so what date do you make your dummy?


(*) Of course, a better design (1 person can have many cars), so you'd have two tables - person & car with a linking table (or joining table or... (there are lots of names) - the technical name is an associative entity) - then if you required Jim to be included in a report of car ownership, you'd do a LEFT JOIN and Jim's brand would, indeed, appear as NULL - unless you used COALESCE - but that's another day's work!
Lessons:



Use the correct data type(*) for each field




Use NULL's when required, but sparingly, and




Avoid dummy values



(*) On a side note, I've lost track of the number of posts I've seen which start with We have a date field and it's a [VAR]CHAR(10), but my calculations give strange results...


What's the best practices with a date field when you want to fill in the fact that it's not filled in and not leave it NULL?

The Best Practice for [any] data that's "not been filled" in and, therefore, has no meaningful value is to make it NULL.
Why do you feel the need to do otherwise?
If you really, really want to avoid NULLs - and, yes, there are some Good Reasons for doing so - then use a separate, "flag" field to indicate the presence (or absence) of the date value.
Using a hard-coded, "default" value, no matter which one you choose, will always come back to bite you in the end.

Generally null is good for missing or unknown values.
However if you're trying to represent historical data, then sentinel values for "since the start" or "current" in to/from scenarios can work better than nulls because your query will not need "or x is null" type constrcts. These can result in non optimal plans.
